# strange javascript IE bug, variable in class clears

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've got a problem, so:

```
var pager = new Array();
var Imtech = {};
Imtech.Pager = function() {
    this.paragraphs = '';
    this.showPage = function() {
        console.log(this.paragraphs.html());
    }
}
```

What i do:

```
pager[0] = new Imtech.pager();
pager[0].paragraphs = $('some obj name here');
pager[0].showPage();
pager[0].showPage();
```

So, i ve got arr of paginating classes;
When i call method `pager[0].showPage()`; - its all ok
But when i try to make it again `pager[0].showPage()` - i got empty result...

Even got no ideas where is mistake; and var clears not only after console.log(), but after any operation...

**How I decided problem:**

So I made a very very bad version, but for ie it works fine;
The problem was, that after first usage of stored DOM element, all innerHTML cleared, but objects still existed; I decided to store innerHTML like a text string; smth like:

```
pager[0].innerHTML = $('some obj name here').html();
```

And when i need this inneHTML like obj I can make obj, so it's not brilliant variant, but in ie (& other browsers) works fine.

Comment: The code, as posted, can't be complete.  If `this.paragraphs` is equal to `''`, then `this.paragraphs.html()` must fail with an unknown method/function.

Comment: :) oh sry, ofcource i pass some object *corrected

Comment: So, topic closed. Dunno why innerhtml of dom element cleared..) tried to keep info in string vars

Comment: You never posted updated, functional, code.

Comment: ok, I posted decr of troubles, thx u!